# How to test for list equality regardless of order?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, equality, testthat

I'm using the **testthat** framework, but this question should fit in a larger background. Basically, I have a function that outputs this

```
list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"))
```

However, I don't care about the order, so this is also completely fine

```
list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-")
```

How do I test for equality with `expect_equal`? I was considering `unlist` followed by a `sort`, but that would break the nested structure.

Answer (score 2):

`sort()` and `unlist()` would likely be the best bet.

```
identical(sort(unlist(a1)), sort(unlist(b1)))
```

You expressed hesitation about breaking the nested structure but note the `sort(unlist(...))` isn't permanent. You can still access either list without a problem.

Also, while I'm unfamiliar with the `testthat` package, `expect_equal` or `expect_identical` should provide similar results although if they are equal, the statement executes silently.

```
> identical(sort(unlist(a1)), sort(unlist(b1)))
[1] TRUE
> a1
[[1]]
[1] "PL+"

[[2]]
[1] "PW-"

[[3]]
[1] "PL+"

[[4]]
[1] "PW-"

[[5]]
[1] "PL+" "PW-"
```

**Data** h/t to @camille for the data.

```
a1 <- list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"))
b1 <- list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map_depth` to sort the nested lists, then check the lists with `setdiff`. If the length when you call `setdiff` is 0, the lists contain the same elements. The tricky thing is that `setdiff` will yield different results based on the order of its arguments, so you end up calling it twice, once from each direction. This is similar to the double checking done in `testthat::expect_setequal`.

For simplicity, I'm wrapping this in a function. You could instead do the same thing with a combination of `all` and `%in%`, but this seemed for compact.

```r
a1 <- list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"))
b1 <- list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-")

nested_equal <- function(l1, l2) {
  left_diff <- setdiff(
    purrr::map_depth(l1, 1, sort),
    purrr::map_depth(l2, 1, sort)
  )
  right_diff <- setdiff(
    purrr::map_depth(l2, 1, sort),
    purrr::map_depth(l1, 1, sort)
  )
  (length(left_diff) == 0) & (length(right_diff) == 0)
}

nested_equal(a1, b1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

A few test cases with different elements:

```r
a2 <- list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"), "A")
b2 <- list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-")

nested_equal(a2, b2)
#> [1] FALSE

a3 <- list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"))
b3 <- list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+", "X"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-", "B")

nested_equal(a3, b3)
#> [1] FALSE
```

To fit in with `testthat` tests, you could test against a true or false value returned by `nested_equal` in `expect_equal`, `expect_true`, `expect_false`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the elements of the lists and check against one another

```
l1 = list("PL+", "PW-", "PL+", "PW-", c("PL+", "PW-"))
l2 = list("PL+", c("PW-", "PL+"), "PL+", "PW-", "PW-")
temp = sapply(l1, function(x) sapply(l2, function(y) identical(sort(x), sort(y))))
all(rowSums(temp) > 0) & all(colSums(temp) > 0)
#[1] TRUE
```